# Ajax Search as user types

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a search feature that I am trying to implement. I would like the user to be able to type their "Search" and ajax fires as the user types to assist with finding their "Search".

I would like the user to be able to type their "Search" and ajax fires as the user types to assist with finding their "Search".

This is what I have; This is working but requires the user to hit search.

```
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                        // Let us trigger the search if the user clicks on the search button.
                        $('.btnSearch').click(function(){
                            makeAjaxRequest();
                        });
                        // Let us trigger the search if the user submit the form by an enter.
                        $('form').submit(function(e){
                                e.preventDefault();
                                makeAjaxRequest();
                            return false; 
                        });

                        function makeAjaxRequest() {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'searchAction.php',
                                data: {name: $('input#name').val()},
                                type: 'get',
                                success: function(response) {
                                    $('table#resultTable tbody').html(response);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I would like the user to be able to type their "Search" and ajax fires as the user types to assist with finding their "Search". Is the question. How do I do it? What do I need to do?

Comment: $(input).change(fn...) should detect changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind your function to the `keyup`-event of the input field.

Adding the following line of code inside the `$(document).ready()`-function

```
$( "#name" ).keyup(makeAjaxRequest);
```

could do the trick for you.

To only perform the AJAX request on a minimum length of three chars in the input field, you can change your `makeAjaxRequest()` function like so:

```
function makeAjaxRequest() {
  if($('input#name').val().length > 2) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'searchAction.php',
      data: {name: $('input#name').val()},
      type: 'get',
      success: function(response) {
        $('table#resultTable tbody').html(response);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind altering my OP code to reflect your suggestions. I am not understanding what I would need to do to "bind your function". I know PHP, but havent learned javascript/ajax all that well yet. (Learning now :D )

Comment: Just add the line of code to your script, for example right above the 
```$('.btnSearch').click(function(){...}```

Comment: Awesome! Works!. How would I restrict search from firing until 3 chars or more have been inputted?

Comment: @Levi - i just answered that very question. see my post.

Comment: Thx, however this is what I need. I like your approach though.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't mention, that I edited my answer to do the "3 or more characters"-thing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to do your search on keyup as that would require 5 ajax calls to be made for the user to search for the word "Hello."

Consider the Google search bar: It will automatically show search results when it thinks it knows what you want, but not on every keystroke.

I wrote a little [event plugin](https://github.com/Pamblam/textChange) for jQuery that does this. It's only 20 lines of code fully formatted. Copy it and change it to your liking or use it as is.. Here's an example:

```
    <script src='//raw.githubusercontent.com/Pamblam/textChange/master/textChange.js'>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('input#name').textChange(makeAjaxRequest);
            function makeAjaxRequest() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'searchAction.php',
                    data: {name: $('input#name').val()},
                    type: 'get',
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('table#resultTable tbody').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

```js
$("input").keyup(function(){
  $("#keyup").text("keyup: "+$(this).val());
});
$("input").textChange(function(){
  $("#textchange").text("textchange: "+$(this).val());
});
```

```css
b{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='//raw.githubusercontent.com/Pamblam/textChange/master/textChange.js'></script>

<b>Type a few words:</b>
<input autofocus />
<div id='keyup'>keyup: </div>
<div id='textchange'>textchange: </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats it might be posible with Jquery Ui autocomplete.

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/